# ios redirect to parent window after authentication

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am logging in facebook through third party api http://api.kliqmobile.com/v1/auth/facebook

my code to logging

```
-(void)loginForFaceBook
{
    NSString *strMediaIconUrl = @"api.kliqmobile.com/v1/auth/google";
    NSString *strurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@",strMediaIconUrl];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strurl]];
}
```

this code is executed on a button click in `viewconrollerA`.
what i want, it comes to `viewcontrollerA`  after authentication in browser.

it is mention in API doc about redirection like this

> After authenticating and authorizing KLIQ for access to the address
>   book, the user will get redirected to our callback URL with a
>   temporary code in a code parameter:
>
> ```
> GET /auth/:id/callback
> ```
>
> The id can be one of google, twitter, facebook, yahoo or linkedin
>
> Full URL example: GET https://api.kliqmobile.com/v1/auth/twitter
>
> This callback stores the user’s access token, and a background process
>   is started that synchronizes all contacts from the address book of the
>   social network into KLIQ.

but i don't know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the "Callback" url of your app, where the browser can redirect authentication parameters after authentication. 
Read the documentation for the api, which must be mentioning about the calback and "url-types" you need to specify at info.plist.

Comment: i have set the callback url as it is given in documention for api like this https://api.kliqmobile.com/v1/auth/google/callback for url Schema in info.plist but its not working.